# How do I update an an array, within an object, within an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I'm currently working with the Node.js MongoDB driver, and am faced with a structure that is as follows:

```
users (database)
users (collection)  
    {           
        name: bob,
        data: [         
            {                   
                name: mydata,
                relations: [ ** I want to addToSet here! ** ]                   
            },              
            {                   
                name: mydata2,
                relations: []                   
            }           
        ]           
    },      
    {           
        name: jeff,
        data: [...same stuff...]            
    }
```

So, I have an array, that is within an object, that is within an array, and my aim to add an entry to it.

I realize that this looks like a relational thing that MongoDB is poorly suited for, but I am trying to accommodate some relational data that may be uploaded. Does anyone happen to know a way to do this? Not necessarily in one query, just in any way at all.

Comment: This mongoshell command might be useful: db.sample.update({'data.name': 'mydata'}, {$addToSet: {'data.$.relations': 4}}, true, true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments by TeTeT, you can do this by using the [`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) positional update operator in conjunction with `$addToSet`.  In the shell:

```
db.users.update(
    {name: 'bob', 'data.name': 'mydata'}, 
    {$addToSet: {'data.$.relations': 'add me'}})
```

The `$` identifies the element in the `data` array that was matched in the query conditions.